# no logro arrancar aplicación con Docker en mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

No logro comprender como arrancar mi aplicación en Docker, intente muchas formas, aquí en esta plataformas, pero no me ha funcionado

esta foto se observa como si funciona utilizando

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

que es, el que trae de prueba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando intento levantar mi aplicación, no funciona solo me sale el error que voy a mostrar en la foto

> Cannot start Docker Compose application. Reason: Error invoking remote
> method 'compose-action': Error: Command failed: wsl -d Ubuntu-18.04 -e
> sh -c "cd "/mnt/c/proyect-shop"; docker compose --file
> "docker-compose.yaml" --project-name "proyect-shop"
> --project-directory "/mnt/c/proyect-shop" up -d" Container teslo-database Created Container teslo-database Starting Error
> response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP
> 0.0.0.0:27017 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:27017: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
> normally permitted.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá les voy a dejar mi  docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
  teslodb:
    image: mongo:5.0.0
    container_name: teslo-database
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes: 
      - /mongo:/data/db
```

por favor cualquier otra cosa que necesites para comprender mi problema, hágamelo saber en comentarios

Comment: Todo indica que ya tienes otro proceso en tu máquina usando el puerto 27017, porque te está diciendo que no lo puede usar.

Comment: ejecuta el comando `docker ps` para que veas cuales contenedores tienes en ejecucion y ver si tienes algun contenedor con el puerto 27017 que es el que tiene mongo por defecto, si tienes un contenedor pues detenlo o eliminalo

Comment: gracias por contestar, no tengo contenedores

Comment: Entonces alguien más en tu OS ya tiene ese puerto ocupado

Comment: gracias por responder, como podría saber si el puerto esta ocupado

Comment: Depende del OS. Revisa cómo ver eso en tu OS

Comment: Por lo general MongoDB es quien usa ese puerto. Verifica si tienes MongoDB instalado y escuchando en dicho puerto en el equipo donde estás tratando de levantar tu imagen de Docker

Comment: gracias por responder, ya lo verifique y corre en el puerto 27017,tambien lo e intentado con otro puerto y nada, no lo logro dar, e intentado casi todo lo que se encuentra en esta plataforma.